# Invalid command name "exit" while executing "exit"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

When I was executing some code on my computer (macOS Sierra, 10.12.3,) I couldn't quit the program in the second window using the 'quit' in the dock or with command-Q. I got this feedback

```
invalid command name "exit"
    while executing
"exit"
```

from PyCharm.

I tried running the same script in IDLE (Python 3.6) and Terminal (Python 2.7), and they all produced the same problem (although there was no print out from IDLE).

No matter how many times I press command-Q, the window was still there, although I can still quit the window using window manager. Can someone please tell me why was the problem? The following code is the simplest version that can reproduce the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

first = tk.Tk()
first_frame = tk.Frame(first, height=10, width=200)
first.wm_title("")
frame = tk.Frame(first)
tk.Button(frame, text="Next", command=lambda: first.destroy()).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
tk.Button(frame,text="Quit",command=lambda: quit()).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
first.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: quit())
first.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.title('')
test=tk.Label(root,text='test')
test.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Cmd-Q (i.e. the "Python" menu) gets instantiated by the first mainloop.

I have the following code snippet that induces the same same behavior:

```
def x_out():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
         root.destroy()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)

menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=x_out)
```

If I File -> Exit then Cmd-Q, I get the same behavior as you. If I just Cmd-Q, no problem. It seems the solution would be to make sure that your first.mainloop() is closed LAST. i.e. don't call first.destroy() until after root.destroy()

Comment: Make sure that when you answer, it is supposed to answer the question, not tell other people that you have the same problem or only tell what causes the problem.